# Find the rank of the matrix operator

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I have the following problem:

> Find the rank of the operator on the vector space of real 3x3 matrices
> translating matrix X into AX-XA with $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & -1
> \end{pmatrix}$$

I started with computing $AX-XA$ for a given $X=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & j
\end{pmatrix}$

$$BX = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2c\\
0 & 0 & 2f\\
-2g & -2h & 0
\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow rank(BX) = 2 = dim(Im(B)) = rank(B)$$

But in the solution I have 4 as the answer. How is it possible? The maximal rank we can have here is 3. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrices $BX$ are spanned by FOUR vectors (corresponding to $c, f, g, h$) so the rank is equal to four. The fact that the elements of that vector space all have rank two is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I understand now. The dimension of image is defined by 4 real numbers.

Comment: But then matrix B is not in vector space of real 3x3 matrices. Is it possible?